# Ruby: elegant array initialization and return in Ruby

Tags: ruby, functional-programming, initialization

I have a method:

```
def deltas_to_board_locations(deltas, x, y)
    board_coords = []
    deltas.each_slice(2) do |slice|
      board_coords << x + slice[0] 
      board_coords << y + slice[1]
    end
    board_coords
  end
```

where deltas is an array, and x,y are fixnums.

Is there a way to eliminate the first and last line to make the method more elegant?

Like:

```
def deltas_to_board_locations(deltas, x, y)
    deltas.each_slice(2) do |slice|
      board_coords << x + slice[0] 
      board_coords << y + slice[1]
    end
  end
```

Comment: KISS ⇒ Keep It Simple Stupid… If it works and is understandable, why should you need a more elegant solution?

Comment: @Renaud Fair enough. Context: I've been charged with refactoring my code to remove complexity and duplication. This was part of that overall effort.

Comment: @steve_gallagher But there's neither duplication nor complexity in that, it's just minorly verbose. My answer is a fairly straight-forward one-liner, but is it "less complex"?

Comment: @Renaud: using the pattern "empty array + loop + push + return array" in a language that supports functional programming is somewhat dubious. A map is two lines shorter and more clear.

Comment: @tokland: I tend to use functional programming idioms when I can, so that when it's something else, I immediately think "Ok, I'm doing something non-standard here. Proceed with caution."

Comment: @Dave Newton I should have added extraneous code to the list with duplicative and overly complex code. This, I thought, was an example of extraneous code that I could get rid of. I had a feeling that, seeing how Ruby can perform complex behavior in a single line, it surely can perform basic behavior, like initialization and return, in a single line as well.

Comment: @steve_gallagher And it can, in at least two ways--my point is that (a) there may be better targets, and (b) this code isn't repetitive and complex, it's just minorly verbose.

Comment: @Dave: Certainly this code in isolation should not be nothing to worry about. But let's look it another way: the first question that comes when seeing the snippet is: "do you known about maps?", "do you know about functional programming?". For the OP those simple concepts may be a tool to improve his code not only here but in hundreds of places (in fact, in the case of FP, it can improve projects as a whole, it did for me at least). Lastly, his asking for better/succinct/elegant ways of doing thing shows interest in improving, which is definitely the way to go in all crafts.

Comment: @tokland Agreed. I still maintain that it's not necessarily the best optimization possible, particularly since the original is noticeably faster than either of our alternatives (not quite twice as fast, but getting there).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
deltas.each_slice(2).flat_map { |dx, dy|
  [x + dx, y + dy]
}
```

The above works for Ruby 1.9 , but I agree with Renaud. The obvious solution is to be preferred, and in this case is faster than mine, too.

**Edit**: Incorporated @tokland's comments.

Comment: Thanks. I know that readability comes first, still it is good to know how to initialize or return more compactly like your methods do.

Comment: Some coments: 1) The argument in the block (`slice`) can be unpacked, 2) The second `inject` is in fact a `flat_map` in disguise (and not very efficient because each iteration creates a new array).

Comment: Took you 10 months to comment? ;) But I agree. I upvoted your answer back then already. But then, it too creates a new array each iteration. My solution creates two though, so yeah :)

Comment: @dominikh: I took a while, yeah :-) Just made the comment because it's the selected answer. The `flat_map` is not important, but the manual argument unpacking hurts a bit...

Comment: @tokland You could always edit the answer ;) I don't expect OP to change the accepted answer.

Comment: I never edit other people's code. And I don't want the OP to change the selected answer, it's info for future readers.

Comment: Well then, future readers won't be bothered with manual unpacking and inject anymore ;)

Answer (score 7):

```
deltas.each_slice(2).flat_map do |dx, dy|
  [x + dx, y + dy]
end
```

Comment: Minor note to future readers; assumes 1.9.2+. But +1, it's faster, and arguably more communicative.

Answer (score 6):

```
deltas.each_with_index.map { |val, idx| val + (idx % 2 == 0 ? x : y )}
```

Whether or not this is "less complex" depends on the audience.

---

Reduction of duplication and complexity should focus on macro-behavior rather than micro-refactoring short, already-readable methods.

Will this rewrite lead to a quantifiably easier-to-understand system? Or are there more important, higher-level issues?

Would enhancing app, class, and method documentation be better? Should those docs be in the code, or in a wiki? Would a picture be worth a thousand lines?

---

Performance comparison vs. @tokland's (his wins by a significant amount). Assuming `deltas` is a million-element array 1-1m. MRI, Ubuntu, old pokey machine.

**My version**

```
deltas.each_with_index.map { |val, idx| val + (idx % 2 == 0 ? x : y )}

Total: 1.764807

 %self     total     self     wait    child    calls  name
100.00      1.76     1.76     0.00     0.00        1  Array#each
  0.00      1.76     0.00     0.00     1.76        1  Global#[No method]
  0.00      1.76     0.00     0.00     1.76        2  Enumerable#each_with_index
  0.00      1.76     0.00     0.00     1.76        1  Enumerable#map
  0.00      1.76     0.00     0.00     1.76        1  Enumerator#each
```

**Better, shorter, more communicative version**

```
deltas.each_slice(2).flat_map { |dx, dy| [x + dx, y + dy] }

Total: 1.236144

 %self     total     self     wait    child    calls  name
100.00      1.24     1.24     0.00     0.00        1  Array#each
  0.00      1.24     0.00     0.00     1.24        1  Global#[No method]
  0.00      1.24     0.00     0.00     1.24        2  Enumerable#each_slice
  0.00      1.24     0.00     0.00     1.24        1  Enumerable#flat_map
  0.00      1.24     0.00     0.00     1.24        1  Enumerator#each
```

**Original version (fastest):**

```
Total: 0.899122

 %self     total     self     wait    child    calls  name
100.00      0.90     0.90     0.00     0.00        1  Array#each
  0.00      0.90     0.00     0.00     0.90        1  Global#[No method]
  0.00      0.90     0.00     0.00     0.90        1  Enumerable#each_slice
```